# Problems with form gsp

Tags: grails

I'm trying to send parameters from my form (gsp) to my controller grails, but doesn't work.

```
<g:form url="[action:'searchByFilter', controller:'invoice']" method="GET">
                    <p>Filtro de busca</p>
                    <g:textField name="search" value="${invoice?.search}" params="search : search"/>
                    <g:submitButton name="search" class="input-search" value="${message(code: 'default.button.search.filter')}" />
</g:form>
```

I need to send input's value to do a result's filter. But, input's value isn't sending.

**My domain class code:**

```
static namedQueries = {
        getInvoicesByStatus {
            eq 'deleted', false
        }

        getInvoicesByFilter {
           eq 'description', Invoice.get(params.search)
        }
    }
```

What's my mistake? I need to use namedQuery :)

Comment: So what is your controller code?

Comment: Your text field and button are both named search, try changing the name of the text field to something different & update controller etc to accommodate.